# Learning About Unit Testing Using When and Should and TDD

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, bdd

The tests at my new job are nothing like the tests I have encountered before.

When they're writing their unit tests (presumably before the code), they create a class starting with "When". The name describes the scenario under which the tests will run (the fixture). They'll created subclasses for each branch through the code. All of the tests within the class start with "should" and they test different aspects of the code after running. So, they will have a method for verifying that each mock (DOC) is called correctly and for checking the return value, if applicable. I am a little confused by this method because it means the exact same execution code is being run for each test and this seems wasteful. I was wondering if there is a technique similar to this that they may have adapted. A link explaining the style and how it is supposed to be implemented would be great. I sounds similar to some approaches of BDD I've seen.

I also noticed that they've moved the repeated calls to "execute" the SUT into the setup methods. This causes issues when they are expecting exceptions, because they can't use built-in tools for performing the check (Python unittest's assertRaises). This also means storing the return value as a backing field of the test class. They also have to store many of the mocks as backing fields. Across class hierarchies it becomes difficult to tell the configuration of each mock.

They also test code a little differently. It really comes down to what they consider an integration test. They mock out anything that steals the context away from the function being tested. This can mean private methods within the same class. I have always limited mocking to resources that can affect the results of the test, such as databases, the file system or dates. I can see some value in this approach. However, the way it is being used now, I can see it leading to fragile tests (tests that break with every code change). I get concerned because without an integration test, in this case, you could be using a 3rd party API incorrectly but your unit tests would still pass. I'd like to learn more about this approach as well.

So, any resources about where to learn more about some of these approaches would be nice. I'd hate to pass up a great learning opportunity just because I don't understand they way they are doing things. I would also like to stop focusing on the negatives of these approaches and see where the benefits come in.

Comment: Take a look on Roy Osherove's resources - [blog](http://osherove.com/blog/) - [art of unit testing, BDD](http://artofunittesting.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you explanation in the first paragraph correctly, that's quite similar to what I often do. (Depending on whether the testing framework makes it easy or not. Also many mocking frameworks don't support it, but spy frameworks like [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) do better.)

For example see the [stack example here](http://specsy.org/documentation.html#isolated_execution_model) which has a common setup (adding things to the stack) and then a bunch of independent tests which each check one thing. [Here's still another example](https://github.com/orfjackal/tdd-tetris-tutorial/blob/beyond/src/test/java/tetris/RemovingFullRowsTest.java), this time one where none of the tests (@Test) modify the common fixture (@Before), but each of them focuses on checking just one independent thing that should happen. If the tests are very well focused, then it should be possible to change the production code to make any single test fail while all other tests pass (I wrote about that recently in [Unit Test Focus Isolation](http://blog.orfjackal.net/2012/05/unit-test-focus-isolation.html)).

The main idea is to have each test check a single feature/behavior, so that when tests fail it's easier to [find out why it failed](http://blog.orfjackal.net/2010/02/three-styles-of-naming-tests.html). See [this TDD tutorial](https://github.com/orfjackal/tdd-tetris-tutorial) for more examples and to learn that style.

I'm not worried about the same code paths executed multiple times, when it takes a millisecond to run one test (if it takes [more than a couple of seconds to run all unit tests](http://arlobelshee.com/what-makes-a-good-test-suite/arlo-belshee), the tests are probably too big). From your explanation I'm more worried that the tests might be too tightly coupled to the implementation, instead of the feature, if it's systematic that there is one test for each mock. The name of the test would be a good indicator of how well structured or how fragile the tests are - does it describe a feature or how that feature is implemented.

About mocking, a good book to read is [Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/). One should not mock 3rd party APIs (APIs which you don't own and can't modify), for the reason you already mentioned, but one should create an abstraction over it which better fits the needs of the system using it and works the way you want it. That abstraction needs to be integration tested with the 3rd party API, but in all tests *using* the abstraction you can mock it.

Comment: I am hoping a similar framework exists for Python. I can see I'm a bit behind on my testing skills. I'll keep reading through these examples. Great stuff!

Comment: I totally see why this approach is better than verifying a handful of mocks at the bottom of a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

First, the pattern that you are using is based on Cucumber - here's a [link](http://cukes.info/).  The style is from the BDD (Behavior-driven development) approach.  It has two advantages over traditional TDD:

1. Language - one of the tenants of BDD is that the language you use influences the thoughts you have by forcing you to speak in the language of the end user, you will end up writing different tests than when you write tests from the focus of a programmer
2. Tests lock code - BDD locks the code at the appropriate level.  One problem common in testing is that you write a large number of tests, which makes your codebase more brittle as when you change the code you must also change a large number of tests too.  BDD forces you to lock the behavior of your code, rather than the implementation of your code.  This way, when a test breaks, it is more likely to be meaningful.

It is worth noting that you do not have to use the Cucumber style of testing to achieve these affects and using it does add an extra layer of overhead.  But very few programmers have been successful in keeping the BDD mindset while using traditional xUnit tools (TDD).

It also sounds like you have some scenarios where you would like to say 'When I do , then verify '.  Because the current BDD xUnit frameworks only allow you to verify primitives (strings, ints, doubles, booleans....), this usually results in a large number of individual tests (one for each Assert).  It is possible to do more complicated verifications using a [Golden Master](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10535414/1335105) paradigm test tool, such as [ApprovalTests](http://www.approvaltests.com).  Here's a [video example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKLUycNLhgc) of this.

Finally, here's a link to Dan North's [blog](http://dannorth.net/) - he started it all.

Comment: Today I started using a library called Pea, a Cucumber-like tool for Python, stripped down to the bare essentials. I am running into issues, though. Mostly, I am seeing the same code duplicated across multiple tests. Also, even though the tests read like prose, there is little to emphasize what changes between tests. Are their techniques to focus on what changes between tests and to eliminate duplication?